# How to resolve conflict with File::Find::Rule and File::Find

Tags: perl

To elaborate,

I am using `File::Find::Rule` to get the path of a specific file which exists in multiple sub directories and sometimes in sub directories directory.

```
File::Find::Rule->file()
                ->name('abc')
                ->in('.');
```

Apart from this, i am using

```
use File::Find;
    find(\&wanted, @directories_to_search);
    sub wanted { ... }
```

Here basically the wanted function is just to change permissions....

The problem is...when I add `File::Find::Rule`, the `find()` function mentioned above says file itself doesn't exist. If I don't add the rule module use then the find part works great

Can anyone help me sort this one. Any ideas here would be helpful. I tried all possible combinations....but nothing works...

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your description of the problem, but I suspect the problem is related to the fact that both

```
use File::Find::Rule;
```

and

```
use File::Find;
```

export a function named `find`. Replace

```
use File::Find::Rule;
```

with

```
use File::Find::Rule qw( );
```

to avoid importing `find` from File::Find::Rule.

Comment: Sorry for incomplete description, but your understanding of the problem is right. Thanks a ton...your answer solved my problem...Thank you ...

Comment: Personally, I always list all exports explicitly, meaning I either use `qw( )` or `qw( foo bar )` on my `use` statements. (strict, warnings, Test::More and Moose being rare exceptions)